# Solving for $(x,y)$ in Pell Equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, pell-type-equations

> **Question:** How would you evaluate Pell Equations of the form $x^2-Dy^2=1$?

I understand that once you are given one solution $(x,y)$ to the $n^{\text{th}}$ power to obtain another solution.

But I am not sure how to find $(x,y)$ without given any other information.

---

**Example:** $x^2-3y^2=1$

By just guessing, I found one pair of solutions as $(x,y)=(2,1)$. So we can generate another set of solutions by raising it the $n^{\text{th}}$ power.$$(2+\sqrt3)^2=7+4\sqrt3\implies (x,y)=(7,4)\tag{A}$$
And on and on. But I'm wondering how you would find the first solution, $(2,1)$ in this case; without given any solution.

I read somewhere that you *could* use continued fractions. If anyone has a method that solves the equation with continued fractions, **please** include that in your answer!

---

**Practice:** For example, how would solve $x^2-19y^2=1$?

Comment: see here for the solutions of a Pell equation https://www.uni-oldenburg.de/fileadmin/user_upload/mathe/personen/steffen.mueller/01lenstra.pdf

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Great pdf, but why did the author remove $3+\sqrt{14}$ in the continued fraction? And how would you use that same method to solve the practice problem I gave?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to find a period in the [continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) of $\sqrt{19}$. Such a period always exists (for sqrt of integer). Doing the expansion, you find $$\sqrt{19}= [4;2,1,3,1,2,4+\sqrt{19}].$$

From that you find a rational approximation to $$\sqrt{19} \approx [4;2,1,3,1,2]= \frac{170}{39}.$$

This is the fundamental solution $$170^2 - 19 \cdot 39^2=1.$$

Comment: Brilliant! Just what I was looking for!

Comment: Hm... then how would you express the continued fraction for $\sqrt{3}$?

Comment: @Frank $\sqrt{3} = 1 + (\sqrt{3} - 1)$, $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}-1} = \dfrac{\sqrt{3} + 1}{2} = 1 + \dfrac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2}$, $\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}-1} = \sqrt{3} + 1$, so $\sqrt{3} = [1; 1, 1+\sqrt{3}]$.

Comment: @Fabian Okay, now I'm confused. I tried to compute $u^2-29v^2=1$, and this is what I got: The continued fraction for $\sqrt{29}$ is$$\sqrt{29}=\left[5;2,1,1,2,5+\sqrt{29}\right]\approx\left[5;2,1,1,2\right]=\dfrac {70}{13}\tag{i}$$But according to Wolfram Mathworld, the solution is $(9801,1820)$ which is indeed equal to $1$. My question is that where did I go wrong? Checking $(70,13)$ gives$$70^2-29\cdot 13^2=-1$$I am very confused...

Comment: @Frank: sometimes, the first period leads to a solution $-1$. Then you have to find the second period: $$\sqrt{29}= [5; 2, 1, 1, 2, 10, 2, 1, 1, 2, 5 + \sqrt{29}]\approx [5; 2, 1, 1, 2, 10, 2, 1, 1, 2] = \frac{9801}{1820}. $$ Note however, that you never have to go beyond the second period.